# Setting up named in arch linux

Tags: linux, dns, arch-linux, bind, nameserver

I am trying to set up a domain on an Arch Linux VM.

Following is my named.conf

```
options {
    directory "/var/named";
    pid-file "/run/named/named.pid";

    // Uncomment these to enable IPv6 connections support
    // IPv4 will still work:
    //  listen-on-v6 { any; };
    // Add this for no IPv4:
    //  listen-on { none; };
    listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; any; };
    allow-query { localhost; any; };
    allow-recursion { 127.0.0.1; };
    allow-transfer { none; };
    allow-update { none; };

    version none;
    hostname none;
    server-id none;
};

zone "localhost" IN {
    type master;
    file "localhost.zone";
};
// ...
zone "DOMAIN.com" IN {
        type master;
        file "DOMAIN.com.zone";
        allow-update { none; };
        notify no;
};
```

In `/var/named/DOMAIN.com.zone`

```
$TTL 7200
; DOMAIN.com
@       IN      SOA     ns1.DOMAIN.com. postmaster.DOMAIN.com. (
                                        2018111111 ; Serial
                                        28800      ; Refresh
                                        1800       ; Retry
                                        604800     ; Expire - 1 week
                                        86400 )    ; Negative Cache TTL
@               IN      NS      ns1.DOMAIN.com
@               IN      NS      ns2.DOMAIN.com
ns1.DOMAIN.com             IN      A       PUBLIC_IP_OF_VM
ns2.DOMAIN.com             IN      A       PUBLIC_IP_OF_VM
ns1     IN      A       PUBLIC_IP_OF_VM
ns2     IN      A       PUBLIC_IP_OF_VM
www     IN      A       PUBLIC_IP_OF_VM
```

In `/etc/resolv.conf` I have

```
search DOMAIN.com
nameserver PRIVATE_IP_OF_VM
```

Then I checked the configuration

```
$ sudo named-checkzone DOMAIN.com /var/named/DOMAIN.com.zone
zone weerepublic.com/IN: loaded serial 2018111111
OK
```

But when I ping `DOMAIN.com` I get Name or service not known. How do I fix this ?

```
$ sudo netstat -nap | grep 53 |grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5355            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      329/systemd-resolve 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      329/systemd-resolve 
tcp6       0      0 :::5355                 :::*                    LISTEN      329/systemd-resolve
```

**EDIT**

The problem was with the log file. `start`, `restart` didn't report any failure. However `systemctl status named` reported

```
isc_stdio_open '/var/log/named.log' failed: permission denied
```

So I touched `/var/log/named.log` and changed ownership to `named:root`. Now the dns server is running.

But external pings is reporting `No address associated with hostname`

So I added `A` record for the DOMAIN.com. The current zonefile looks like the following.

```
$TTL 7200
; DOMAIN.com
@       IN      SOA     ns1.DOMAIN.com. postmaster.DOMAIN.com. (
                                        2018111111 ; Serial
                                        28800      ; Refresh
                                        1800       ; Retry
                                        604800     ; Expire - 1 week
                                        86400 )    ; Negative Cache TTL
@               IN      NS      ns1.DOMAIN.com.
@               IN      NS      ns2.DOMAIN.com.
DOMAIN.com.             IN      A       PUBLIC_IP_OF_VM
ns1.DOMAIN.com.             IN      A       PUBLIC_IP_OF_VM
ns2.DOMAIN.com.             IN      A       PUBLIC_IP_OF_VM
ns1     IN      A       PUBLIC_IP_OF_VM
ns2     IN      A       PUBLIC_IP_OF_VM
www     IN      A       PUBLIC_IP_OF_VM
```

Then I restarted `named` But still external pings are reporting

```
No address associated with hostname
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "_I do not get any response_"? Does `ping` sit quietly and literally do nothing? Does it return immediately? Does it return an error message and if so, what? Does the name `DOMAIN.com` translate to the expected address? Does `ping` try to send packets, and if so is it to the expected address?

Comment: Have you (re)started the nameserver? Is your system configured to use the nameserver you've just set up?

Comment: The hostname DOMAIN.com is not resolved. I get Name or Service not known. I have included it in question. Yes named is restarted and even the entire VM is restarted too.

Comment: `nslookup DOMAIN.com 127.0.0.1` or (better) `dig @127.0.0.1 DOMAIN.com`. Any correct result from either?

Comment: Connection times out. No server could be reached. In my `resolv.conf` I have included the private IP of the VM. Is that a problem ?

Comment: Three entries. updaded in question.

Comment: As the error message asks, please run it as root

Comment: Updated. Same response.

Answer (score 0):

Your nameserver isn't running. Perhaps there's an error when you try to start it, or perhaps you're not starting it correctly. Either way, it's not running.

This can be seen from the `netstat` output you have provided in your question:

> ```
> Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
> tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5355            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      329/systemd-resolve
> tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      329/systemd-resolve
> tcp6       0      0 :::5355                 :::*                    LISTEN      329/systemd-resolve
> ```

The first and third entries are for port 5353 rather than port 53 and so can be ignored. The second entry is for 127.0.0.53 rather than 127.0.0.1 and again can be ignored. Finally, it can be seen that all of them are from `systemd-resolve` rather than your own nameserver.

Comment: The `start`, `restart` commands were not giving any clue. But when I checked `status` I saw its not running with error `isc_stdio_open '/var/log/named.log' failed: permission denied`. So I toughed `/var/log/named.log` as root. But that didn't work. What should I do now ?

Comment: Thanks after chown `named:root`. Now dig works. but ping from external systems reports `No address  associated with hostname`. Updating question.

Comment: Can the external systems access your nameserver? If not, they're not going to be able to use it to resolve the name. Do they know they're supposed to use it? If not, hey're not going to use it to resolve the name. My recommendation? Put the relevant records in the DNS using the Domain Management Control Panel that your Domain Registrar probably already offers you.

Comment: Thanks, It took some time. Then it all started automatically after the log issue was resolved.